# Azure OpenAI latency spikes (3-20 minutes!)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, openai-api, gpt-3

We're prototyping a chatbot application using Azure OpenAI gpt-3.5-turbo model using the standard tier.

We're facing random latency bursts, which sometimes go between 3-20 minutes. Below I have screenshots with the metrics provided by the portal. As you can see the usage/rate limit don't indicate high load.

In fact, the application isn't yet deployed on production, it's only being used for testing purposes by our development team. Understanding these latency spikes will help us prove our PoC and use Azure OpenAI service on production.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

**Model Properties**
Model name: gpt-35-turbo
Model version: 0301
Deployment type: Standard
Content Filter: Default
Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands): 120
Rate limit (Tokens per minute): 120000
Rate limit (Requests per minute): 720

**Diagrams**

Latency:
[image]

Rate limit:
[image]

Processed prompt tokens:
[image]

Comment: I´m having the same problem. I delete extra models to have the full quota for gpt-35-turbo-0301 without any improvements. Do you find any solution?